# C# OpenGL Draw Stretched 2D texture (not resize!)

Tags: c#, opengl, draw, texture2d

i am trying to draw a button from such texture:
[image]
And do this via that way:

```
    //sWidth, sHeight - stretched size.
    Size mySize = TheSprite.MyTexture.TextureSize;
    OpenGL.glBindTexture(OpenGL.TextureTarget.Texture2D, TheSprite.MyTexture.MyTextureID);
    OpenGL.glBegin(OpenGL.BeginMode.Quads);
    double x = (double)TheDestination.Left;
    double y = (double)TheDestination.Top;
    double s = (double)(TheSprite.MyLocation.Left + TheSource.Left) / (double)mySize.Width + sWidth;
    double t = (double)(TheSprite.MyLocation.Top + TheSource.Top) / (double)mySize.Height + sHeight;
    double x2 = (double)TheDestination.Right + sWidth;
    double s2 = (double)(TheSprite.MyLocation.Left + TheSource.Right) / (double)mySize.Width + sWidth;
    double y2 = (double)TheDestination.Bottom + sHeight;
    double t2 = (double)(TheSprite.MyLocation.Top + TheSource.Bottom) / (double)mySize.Height + sHeight;

    OpenGL.glColor4(TheModulation);

    OpenGL.glTexCoord2d(s, t2);
    OpenGL.glVertex2d(x, y2);
    OpenGL.glTexCoord2d(s, t);
    OpenGL.glVertex2d(x, y);
    OpenGL.glTexCoord2d(s2, t);
    OpenGL.glVertex2d(x2, y);
    OpenGL.glTexCoord2d(s2, t2);
    OpenGL.glVertex2d(x2, y2);
    OpenGL.glEnd();
```

But in my case, it looks like that:
[image]

instead of something like this (same texture):
[image]

How i should draw it for got it stretched, not resized in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code

```
OpenGL.glTexCoord2d(s, t2);
OpenGL.glVertex2d(x, y2);
OpenGL.glTexCoord2d(s, t);
OpenGL.glVertex2d(x, y);
OpenGL.glTexCoord2d(s2, t);
OpenGL.glVertex2d(x2, y);
OpenGL.glTexCoord2d(s2, t2);
OpenGL.glVertex2d(x2, y2);
```

you're mapping the corners of the texture to the corners of the button, like this:

[image]

[image]

Since your texture is square and the button is rectangular, the texture is stretched horizontally to fit the width of the button.
If you don't want the yellow frame to be stretched horizontally on the sides of the button, you need to use additional points when mapping the texture in order to stretch horizontally only the middle part of it (points 2-3-6-7). Like this:

[image]

[image]